# Uniform Limit of Riemannian Isometries is also a Riemannian Isometry

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

This is problem 6-3 in Lee's Riemannian Geomtry (I have changed some notation below).

> **Problem.** Let $M$ and $N$ be Riemannian manifolds and let $f_n:M\to N$ be a sequence of Riemannian isometries that converge uniformly to a map $f:M\to N$. Then show that $f$ too is a Riemannian isometry.

Here is what I have thought. We use the face that a map $\varphi:M\to N$ is a Riemannian isometry if and only if $\varphi$ is an isometry under the metrics (in the sense of metric spaces) induced on $M$ and $N$ by the a respective Riemannian metrics.

Thus it is sufficient to prove that $f$ is an isometry in the sense of metric spaces, that is, a *metric isometry*.

Using the uniform convergence and isometry property of $f_n$'s, it is easy to argue that $f$ is injective and continuous.

**I am unable to show that $f$ is surjective**. I tried the following: Let $q$ be an arbitrary point in $N$ and let $p_n\in M$ be the unique point such that $f_n(p_n)=q$. It follows that $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$. But since $M$ is not necessarily complete, we cannot infer that $(p_n)$ converges. If it does converge, say to a point $p$, then once can argue that $f(p)=q$, but there is no guarantee for its convergence.

**EDIT:** To show that $f$ is surjective, we follow Jack Lee's hint below. Let $y\in N$ be a point in the closure of the image of $f$. Let $U$ be a uniformly normal neighborhood of $y$ in $N$, and let $x\in M$ be a point such that $f(x)\in U$. Let $u\in T_{f(x)}N$ be such that $\exp_{f(x)}u=y$, and that the geodesic segment $t\mapsto \exp_{f(x)}(tu):[0, 1]\to N$ is contained in $U$. For each $n$, let $x_n$ be the unique point in $M$ such that $f_n(x_n)=x$. Since each $f_n$ is an isometry, and since isometries pullback geodesics to geodesics, for each $n$ we can find $v_n\in T_{x_n}M$ such that $f_n(\exp_{x_n}v_n)=y$. Expplicitly, $v_n$ is the unique vector in $T_{x_n}M$ such that $df_n|_{x_n}(v_n)=u$. Thus $|v_n|=|u|$. But $|u|$ is same as the length of the aforementioned geodesic segment joining $f(x)$ to $y$. This in turn is same as the distance between $f(x)$ and $y$, for $U$ was chosen to be uniformly normal. Therefore the length of the geodesic segment $t\mapsto \exp_{x_n}(tv_n):[0, 1]\to M$ is same as $d(f(x), y)$ as is also equal to $|v_n|$. What we have just shown is that $|v_n|$ is constant an is equal to $d(f(x), y)$ for each $n$.

It is easy to see that $x_n$ converges to $x$. So for $n$ large enough, we have each $x_n$ in a geodesic ball $B$ about $x$. Without loss of generality we assume that $x_n\in B$ for all $n$. Let $w_n$ be the vector in $T_xM$ obtained by parallel transporting $v_n$ to $x$ via the unique geodesic path joining $x_n$ and $x$ in $B$. Since $w_n$ has the same magnitude as $v_n$, and since the magnitude of $v_n$'s is constant, we have that some subsequence of $(w_n)$ converges to a vector $w\in T_xM$. Again, we may assume that $w_n$ itself converges to $w$, passing to a subsequence if necessary. Now let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x$ in $M$ such that the geodesic exponential map is defined in some open set of $TV$ which contains $V$. We may assume that each $x_n\in V$.

Now the idea is this. Consider the map $\phi$ which eats a pair $(\alpha_n, \beta_n)\in T_xM\times T_xM$, and spits out a point in $TM$ whose fibre is that of $\exp_x(\beta_n)$, and tangent vector is the parallel transport of $\beta_n$ along the geodesic segment $t\mapsto \exp_x(t\alpha_n)$. Of course, this map in only defined on an open subset of $T_xM\times T_xM$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307289/parallel-transport-along-radial-geodesics-yields-a-smooth-vector-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, this is a smooth map. Compose this map by the exponential map. Thus this composite takes $(\alpha_n, w_n)$, where $\alpha_n$ is the "direction which aims at $x_n$", and produces $\exp_{x_n}(v_n)$.

So we have $\phi(\alpha_n, w_n)= \exp_{x_n}(v_n)$, giving $f_n(\phi(\alpha_n, w_n))= f_n(\exp_{x_n}(V_n))= y$. Using uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(\phi(\alpha_n, w_n))= \lim_{n\to infty}f(\phi(\alpha_n, w_n))$$
Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\alpha_n}=0$, and thus we have
$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(\exp_{x_n}(v_n)) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(\phi(\alpha_n, w_n))= f(\phi(0, w)) = f(\exp_xw)$$
showing that $f$ is surjctive.

Comment: You should check if Lee requires isometries to be surjective. Also, he might assume completeness implicitly, otherwise this is indeed unclear.

Comment: In the question Lee has explicitly mentioned that the manifolds are not necessarily complete. Yes, Lee requires isometries to be surjective, but does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm glad you asked this question. It has occurred to me occasionally that this problem is probably too hard without some kind of hint, so I finally sat down and tried to work out a reasonable hint.

Try this: To show that $f$ is surjective, suppose $y$ is a limit point of $f(M)$. Choose $x\in M$ such that $f(x)$ lies in a uniformly normal neighborhood of $y$, and show there exists a convergent sequence of points $(x_n,v_n)\in TM$ such that $f_n(x_n) = f(x)$
and $f_n \big(\exp_{x_n} v_n\big)=y$.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. I think your hint helps. I will try and post the full solution based on your hint by tomorrow.

Comment: Dear Prof. Lee. Thinking about your comment lead me to ask this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307289/parallel-transport-along-radial-geodesics-yields-a-smooth-vector-field Can you please say something about it? Thank you.

Comment: Dear Prof. Lee. I have finally completed the proof of the problem in this post. I have posted my solution above. It is long. But if you can find the time to look at it then I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Could one use Myers-Steenrod here? I ask because these two are consecutive problems in the 2nd edition of your book.

Comment: How does proving that the image is closed prove that the map is surjective? Do we have that the image is also open? And that the manifolds are connected?

Answer (score 2):

If $f_n : (M,g_n)\rightarrow (N,g)$ is an isometry between Riemannian manifolds (that may be compact manifolds, i.e., not complete), then assume that $f_n\rightarrow f$.

Here Riemannian metric $g_n$ is induced from $g$.

**Not surjective case** : Consider $M$ is $[0,1]^2$ and $N$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $f_n(M)$ are "folding", then $f(M)$ may have image $[0,1]\times [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Hence $f$ is not one-to-one.

**Sujective case** : Note that it is bijective so that we have a claim that uniform limit $f$ of isometries on $N$ is isometric. Since $$ d_g(x,y)= d_g(f_n(x),f_n(y)) \rightarrow d_g (f(x),f(y)) $$ then $f$ is isometric.