# Uniform Limit of Riemannian Isometries is a Riemannian isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I have a question from the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296525/uniform-limit-of-riemannian-isometries-is-also-a-riemannian-isometry?rq=1). It shows that if $f_n: M \rightarrow N$ is a sequence of (Riemannian) isometries that converge uniformly to a map $f: M \rightarrow N$, then $f$ is a Riemannian isometry. To do so, we use the fact that Riemannian isometry and distance isometry coincide.

In the proof, Prof. Lee's [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299342/438367) tells us that it is enough to show $f(M)$ is closed. However, from here how do we conclude that $f(M) = N$? Do we have any knowledge that $f(M)$ is open? Any insights into this will be appreciable.

Comment: You should start by defining a Riemannian isometry; from the context, it appears that your definition includes the requirement that it is a diffeomorphism. Then argue that $dim(M)=dim(N)$ and that the differential of each Riemannian isometry in this case is a linear isomorphism at each points. Then use IFT to conclude that each isometry is an open map...

Comment: With the information that is given, we cannot conclude that $f$ is smooth, let alone a local diffeomorphism. The questions asks whether from the knowledge that $f$ is a uniform limit of diffeomorphisms we can conclude that it is a local diffeomorphism (or an open map at the least) to proceed.

Comment: I am not asking about $f$, I am asking about your definition of an isometry.

Comment: The definition of *Riemannian* isometry requires it to be a diffeomorphism. But indeed, one can prove that Riemannian isometries and metric isometries (distance preserving homeomoprhisms) are the same.